# Shankar's definition of adjoint

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, conventions, notation

I think Shankar's definition of adjoint operator (in his QM book) differs from many other sources.
On page 26, he made the definition

$$\langle \Omega V|=\langle V|\Omega^\dagger \quad .$$

Now $\langle V|$ belongs to the dual space (mathematicians use the notation $H'$) of $H$, i.e. the space of all complex linear maps $H\to {\mathbb C}$. In math text books, the action of $\Omega^\dagger$ on $\langle V|$ is, $\langle V|$ compose with $\Omega$, i.e. $\langle V|\Omega^\dagger$ should be the linear map which maps $|W\rangle $ to $\langle V|\Omega W\rangle$. Definition in some physics books, e.g. Griffiths, Peter Woit, seems to be equivalent to this. However, if you use Shankar's definition, $\langle V|\Omega^\dagger$ would have been the linear map which maps $|W\rangle $ to $\langle \Omega V|W\rangle$. If $\Omega$ is not self-adjoint, this is different from the math (and Peter Woit) definition.

Am I understanding this matter correctly?

Comment: Which math books? Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: Most functional analysis books, e.g. John Conway "A course in functional analysis" p31, or Peter Woit's text book page 47.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the math text books, is the inner product also anti-linear in the first entry? Despite that, check e.g. eq. 4.1  of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9907069.pdf).  I don't have the other references (and it would be great if you could include edition/page/eq. number)

Comment: I have no access to the math text books you mentioned, but usually mathematicians define the scalar product in a complex Hilbert space being linear in the left entry and anti-linear in the right, whereas in physics the opposite convention is chosen. Might this be reason for the confusion? (Shankar's definition is correct with the physicist's convention.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743398/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Conway's book (2nd edition) use the mathematicians' convention of sesquilinearity in the *second* entry, which opposite to the physicists' convention.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, mathematical notations can fail. This is one place where Dirac notation fails, and it fails partially by being ambiguous.  Here is how I understand how this works.  Note first that I don't like pulling operators into kets.  I think of the symbols inside a ket as *labels* for the ket, and you can't act with operators on labels.  Thus, here's my way of being careful with matrix elements of non-Hermitian operators.

First, always assume that operators act to the right. That is,
$$
\langle \psi \lvert \hat{\Omega} \rvert \varphi \rangle \to \langle v_\psi,\Omega v_\varphi\rangle\,,
$$
where the second expression is the typical$^1$ mathematical notation for the inner product on a Hilbert space:

- $v_{\psi}$ is an alternative notation for $\lvert \psi \rangle$,
- $\Omega v_\varphi$ is the operation of the operator $\Omega$ on the vector $v_{\varphi}$, represented in Dirac notation as $\hat{\Omega}\lvert \phi \rangle$, and
- $\langle v_\psi,\Omega v_\varphi\rangle$ is the inner product of $\Omega v_\varphi$ with $v_{\psi}$.

Thus, I always interpret $\langle \psi \lvert \hat{\Omega} \rvert \varphi \rangle$ as $\langle \psi \lvert \left(\hat{\Omega} \rvert \varphi \rangle\right)$, even if there is an adjoint, i.e., it's also true that
$$
\langle \psi \lvert \hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \varphi \rangle
= \langle \psi \lvert \left(\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \varphi \rangle\right)\,.
$$

Now, what about if we wanted to take the inner product in the other direction? Let's trace this through:
$$
\langle \Omega v_\psi, v_\varphi\rangle
=
\langle  v_\psi, \Omega^{\dagger}v_\varphi\rangle
"="
\langle \psi \lvert \left(\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \varphi \rangle\right)
=
\langle \psi \lvert \hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \varphi \rangle\,.
$$
This here is what is *really* meant by the notation $\langle \Omega \psi \lvert = \langle  \psi \lvert\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger}$: it's that the $\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger}$ actually acts *to the right* on whatever kets are going to be put in that spot.  You do *not* think of this as $\Omega^{\dagger}$ acting to the left. This is the answer to your following complaint:

> In math text books, the action of $\Omega^\dagger$ on $\langle V|$ is, $\langle V|$ compose with $\Omega$, i.e. $\langle V|\Omega^\dagger$ should be the linear map which maps $|W\rangle $ to $\langle V|\Omega W\rangle$.

Well, $\langle  V \lvert\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger}$ does not represent the action of $\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger}$ on $\langle V\rvert$. It represents the action of ${\hat{\Omega}}$ on $\lvert V\rangle$, than conjugated.  That is, again,
$$
\langle  V \lvert\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert U \rangle
"="
\langle V, \Omega^{\dagger} U\rangle
=
\langle \Omega V, U\rangle\,,
$$
with a slight abuse of (my) notation where I am identifying $V$ (math notation) with $\lvert V \rangle$ (Dirac notation).

We could take this one step further and try to represent this more explicitly in the Dirac notation as
$$
\left(\hat{\Omega}\lvert V \rangle\right)^{\dagger}\lvert U \rangle
=
\langle V \lvert \hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert U \rangle\,,
$$
where the second expression is understood to be equivalent to $\langle V \lvert \left(\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert U \rangle\right)$.

---

Note that this is consistent with the mathematical notation as well:
\begin{align}
\langle \psi \lvert \hat{\Omega} \rvert \varphi \rangle
"="
\langle v_\psi,\Omega v_\varphi\rangle
=
\langle \Omega^{\dagger}v_\psi, v_\varphi\rangle
=
\langle v_\varphi, \Omega^{\dagger} v_\psi\rangle^*
"="
\left(\langle \varphi \lvert \left(\hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \psi \rangle\right)\right)^*
=
\langle \varphi \lvert \hat{\Omega}^{\dagger} \rvert \psi \rangle^*\,.
\end{align}

---

<sub>$^1$ Up to the order of the vectors. I've often seen this where the inner product is linear in the *first* argument rather than the second and anti-linear in the second rather than the frst, but I'll do it the other way that matches the Dirac notation better.</sub>